# Vscode show all lines of file as a git change

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I do a merge that ends into a conflict vscode is showing all the file lines as one big change so.. or I accept the new or the old file, but when I click on "Compare changes" it shows me the real changes. I need it to show that changes one by one so I accept or reject them one by one, these images may help you to understand. I'm using WSL2 and did the merge with sourcetree.

Here I can only accept or reject all changes at once
[All changes as one big change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH1w5.jpg)

Here I can see the real changes one by one. I need that way in the previews image.
[All changes one by one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNeQn.jpg)

Comment: Is it possible that something changed on all lines in the incoming file ? for example : line endings ?

Comment: what do you see if you use an external 3-way mergetool for git and use command: `git mergetool`

Comment: The problem was the line endings as LeGEC said, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The comment from LeGEC solved the problem.